# Should I pass session data from my controller, or read it in the service layer?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a fairly typical MVC application in PHP.  Quite often I need to grab data from the session but I'm never sure if I should do this in the controller, or in the service.

For example, if a request hits `domain.com/user/edit`, my controller could get the current user from the session and pass it to the service, or the service could access the session itself.

If I do it in the service it creates a dependency between the service layer and the session object.  If I do it in the controller, it makes the controller a bit fatter.

I know it's only a small point but I have a lot of (small) variables stored in the session, and parameter handling for my requests is quite complex in itself.

Thanks!

Comment: What MVC are you using? Almost every MVC has an AppController. It's better to check whether the session is set or not? Then set the session in a class variable. So this class variable will be accessible from any controller when you extend AppController. Secondly, set this class variable in view variable from AppController, like this: $this->set('user_session',$this->session). So you can access this view variable in every view files. Hope I make it clear for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** neither.

Now a bit loner explanation ...

From architectural point of view, the session is form of storage. And in PHP it is quite easy to manipulate which type of storage it actually is.

The services in MVC are the part of model layer which handles the *application logic*. That is - it deals with interaction between [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and storage abstraction (that usually are implemented directly or indirectly as [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)).

Therefore, you should abstract the `$_SESSION` accesses (an also initialization) as some sort of `SessionMapper`, which can handle the storage of domain objects as whole or just storage of specific parameters from those domain objects.

And since session is (usually) a singular structure within your execution if request, you can enforce that by making sure the `Factory`, which produces the data mappers, creates only one instance of said `SessionMapper`.

Services only use this (shared via factory) session mapper and controller do not know anything about it.

Answer (score -3):

`$_SESSION` is a global variable. Why do you have to pass something that can be accessed globally?

Unless the session data needs to be validated and the its data needs to be prepared in some way, there is no need to pass such variables to a controller class.

Comment: "Why do you have to pass something that can be accessed globally?" Because you want to prevent tight coupling of (super)globals in OOP.

Comment: @PeeHaa, That totally depends on the implication itself, if the data source varies between SESSION or other forms then passing them sounds good, otherwise not.